# Simple Algebra Problem, which I can't solve. (Fractions and things of that kind.)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to solve equation 1 for β, I know, from checking, that the answer is equation 2. But, I cannot find a way to get to it from equation 1. So, the question is: how do I get to equation 2 from equation 1?

1. $$ V_{app} =\frac {\beta c \sin \theta }{1-\beta \cos \theta} $$
2. $$ \beta = \frac {V_{app}}{V_{app}\cos \theta + c \sin \theta}$$

P.S. Even though this problem is from a physics exercise, I decided to include it in here; as I only care about the mathematics in question, algebra in this case.

P.P.S. I'm sorry if the tag "algebra-precalculus" isn't correct. It was the closest thing to the subject I could find (since algebra alone was not accepted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$V_{app} =\frac {\beta c \sin \theta }{1-\beta \cos \theta}\\(1-\beta \cos \theta)V_{app} =\beta c \sin \theta\\
V_{app}=\beta c \sin \theta+V_{app}\beta \cos \theta\\
\beta=\frac{V_{app}}{ c \sin \theta+V_{app} \cos \theta}$$
You lost a term in the denominator

Comment: Thank you. There were some algebraic rules evolved with which I was not familiar. But now I am aware of their existence, thanks to you.